# Multiple files created by arecord

Tags: audio, embedded-linux, alsa, buildroot

I've made custom distribution using buildroot, with hard-flow for ARMv7 processor.
Everything is working except....

```
# arecord -D hw:0,0 -fdat -d 5 test.wav
```

This makes multiple files. Thousands of them.

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        958508 Jan  1 00:19 test-01.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-02.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-03.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-04.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-05.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-06.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-07.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-08.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-09.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-10.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-100.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-101.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-102.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-103.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-104.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-105.wav
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jan  1 00:19 test-106.wav
```

And so on...

This happens if I pass -d parameter. Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the audio settings with *amixer* or *alsamixer*?  You need to enable record sources.  I guess you mean *hard-float*?  But that should not matter.  You might also try `-N`, in case the driver is buggy.

Comment: In theory, the first file should have 960044 bytes. This looks as if 64-bit arithmetic is not handled correctly.

Answer (score 7):

The problem seems to appear on ARM architecture starting from **1.0.28** `arecord` version (`arecord --version`).
On Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie I managed to downgrade `alsa-utils` from `1.0.28-1` to `1.0.25-4` (rolling back to Wheezy's repo), so that fixed the problem:

- `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
- add the following line to the end of the file `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo aptitude versions alsa-utils` (this should show the old version to become available)
- `sudo apt-get install alsa-utils=1.0.25-4`
- now `arecord --version` should display downgraded version `1.0.25`
- You probably now want to remove that line you added to /etc/apt/sources.list, so that you don't get other packages from wheezy
- `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
- remove the line `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi`
- run apt-get update again
- also, put alsa-utils on hold so it doesn't get upgraded
- `sudo apt-mark hold alsa-utils`

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative solution is to upgraded alsa-utils to the latest version 1.1.3 from source. This is how I have done it on my Raspberry Pi 3

1. `mkdir ~/alsa-utils`
2. `cd ~/alsa-utils/`
3. `wget ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/utils/alsa-utils-1.1.3.tar.bz2`
4. `tar xvjf alsa-utils-1.1.3.tar.bz2`
5. `cd ~/alsa-utils/alsa-utils-1.1.3/`
6. `sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev`
7. `./configure --disable-alsaconf --disable-bat --disable-xmlto --with-curses=ncursesw`
8. `make`
9. `sudo make install`
10. `arecord --version`

Comment: Latest version as of 2018 January is 1.1.5, just update the version number accordingly in the commands.