# Multiple files created by arecord -d

Tags: audio-recording, raspberry-pi3, alsa

Using "arecord -d 5 filename.wav" does not stop recording unless interrupted with ctl+c and produces multiple wav files after the 5 second initial file.
While I realize this has been asked before...
[Multiple files created by arecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629915/multiple-files-created-by-arecord#)
...I have been trying arecord on a couple of different images, both Jessie on RPi3's.
Both have Alsamixer v1.0.28. (both have arecord v1.0.28).

The image at fault
cat /proc/asound/version
  Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.9.28-v7+

The good image
  Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.9.32-v7+

I will try upgrading alsa-utils from source.

My current work-around is "sudo timeout 5 arecord filename.wav"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the bug that was [fixed](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-utils.git;a=commit;h=8f361d83cfcb39887f5fc591633e68d9448e3425) in alsa-utils 1.0.29 (years ago).

As long as Raspbian stays on Jessie and does not upgrade its packages, you have to upgrade yourself.